# Customize login in Grails Spring Security plugin

Tags: authentication, grails, spring-security

I have an application where the login should include an organization number, so the login needs to be **username + password + organization number**.

Sample case: If the **username + password** matches with an existing user, I need to check if that user has the organization id. If not, the login should fail.

I saw that the login form from spring security plugin submits to `/app/j_spring_security_check` but couldn't find where that is actually implemented.

Also I'm not sure if touching that is the right way of implementing this custom login.

My question is where / how to customize the login action? (to make it fail on the case I described above).

Answer (score 1):

We can do this by overriding the filter UserNamePasswordAuthenticationFilter and provide our custom attemptAuthentication.
So, go to DefaultSecurityConfig.groovy file (inside plugins). See tree diagram below:

```
  target
      |-work
            |-plugins
                    |-spring-security-core-2.0-RC5
                                          |-conf
                                               |-DefaultSecurityConfig.groovy
```

In DefaultSecurityConfig.groovy under apf closure we specify filterProcessUrl which we can override in grails application's Config.groovy like we do for other properties (e.g. rejectIfNoRule)

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.apf.filterProcessesUrl="your url"
```

Now we understood how it checks for authentication.Let's customise it own way by overriding the method **attemptAuthentication** of filter named **UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter**. For example, see below(also, go through the inline comments added there)

```
 package org.springframework.security.web.authentication;
    
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
    import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationServiceException;
    import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
    import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
    import org.springframework.security.core.AuthenticationException;
    import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter;
    import org.springframework.util.Assert;
    
    public class CustomUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter extends AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter {
        public static final String SPRING_SECURITY_FORM_USERNAME_KEY = "j_username";
        public static final String SPRING_SECURITY_FORM_PASSWORD_KEY = "j_password";
        /** @deprecated */
        @Deprecated
        public static final String SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_USERNAME_KEY = "SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_USERNAME";
        private String usernameParameter = "j_username";
        private String passwordParameter = "j_password";
        private String organisationParameter = 'j_organisation'
        private boolean postOnly = true;
    
        public UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter() {
            super("/j_spring_security_check");
        }
    
        public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws AuthenticationException {
            if(this.postOnly && !request.getMethod().equals("POST")) {
                throw new AuthenticationServiceException("Authentication method not supported: " + request.getMethod());
            } else {
                String username = this.obtainUsername(request);
                String password = this.obtainPassword(request);
                String password = this.obtainOrganisation(request);
               
              //regular implementation in spring security plugin   /**
UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authRequest = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, password);
                this.setDetails(request, authRequest);
                return         this.getAuthenticationManager().authenticate(authRequest);
            }
**/

//Your custom implementation goes here(Authenticate on the basis of organisation as well). Here you need to customise authenticate as per your requirement so that it checks for organisation as well.
        }

       protected String obtainOrganisation(HttpServletRequest request) {
        return request.getParameter(this.organisationParameter);
    }    

        protected String obtainPassword(HttpServletRequest request) {
            return request.getParameter(this.passwordParameter);
        }
    
        protected String obtainUsername(HttpServletRequest request) {
            return request.getParameter(this.usernameParameter);
        }
    
        protected void setDetails(HttpServletRequest request, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authRequest) {
            authRequest.setDetails(this.authenticationDetailsSource.buildDetails(request));
        }
    
        public void setUsernameParameter(String usernameParameter) {
            Assert.hasText(usernameParameter, "Username parameter must not be empty or null");
            this.usernameParameter = usernameParameter;
        }
    
        public void setPasswordParameter(String passwordParameter) {
            Assert.hasText(passwordParameter, "Password parameter must not be empty or null");
            this.passwordParameter = passwordParameter;
        }
    
        public void setPostOnly(boolean postOnly) {
            this.postOnly = postOnly;
        }
    
        public final String getUsernameParameter() {
            return this.usernameParameter;
        }
    
        public final String getPasswordParameter() {
            return this.passwordParameter;
        }
    }
```

Hence, it's more of a overriding task in terms of spring security.

To get more clearer idea about same read [this nice link](https://github.com/markkolich/blog/blob/master/content/entries/spring-3-and-spring-security-setting-your-own-custom-j-spring-security-check-filter-processes-url.md) for java
and
for grails read [this](https://objectpartners.com/2013/07/11/custom-authentication-with-the-grails-spring-security-core-plugin/)

Hope it helps.

These blogs gives a more detailed idea of the same requirements.

Comment: Hi Vinay thanks for the explanation. I'n in the process of testing your solution. One question, where do I configure the new CustomUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter to actually filter requests?

Comment: Though you can make it conf directory or in src/groovy and register it in Config.groovy. Not sure in above case what issues we might face. I'm creating a POC project for same and would let you know if it works well and share the git / bitbucket public repo url.

Comment: Studying the spring code, it seems the "spring" way of doing this is a little more complex: 1. create an implementation of AbstractAuthenticationToken to return the Authorization object from the filter, 2. create an AuthenticationProvider implementation to actually do the authentication, like this one: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/authentication/dao/AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.java, 3. I need to register that provider into the ProviderManager (not sure how I do this right now). I'll keep trying.